# Twitter bootstrap modal shows and then disappears

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I went through all possible questions related to Twitter Bootstrap modals but my problem is kind of unique over here.

I have included the files from the latest bootstrap release, so my public directory has -

```
css/
| bootstrap.css
| bootstrap.min.css

js/
| bootstrap.js
| bootstrap.min.js
```

I am also using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) and I have checked that it is not interfering with the bootstrap files.

My modals are defined this way -

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal-<?php echo $user_role->id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Update &ldquo;{{ $user_role->role_name }}&rdquo;</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label>New Value</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="inputId" value="<?php echo $user_role->id ?>">
        <input type="text" name="inputUpdate" value="<?php echo $user_role->role_name ?>" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</a>
        <a rel="update" href="<?php echo url('admin/dashboard/controls/update_master') ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to call the modal, the button is defined like this -

```
<a rel="edit" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-<?php echo $user_role->id ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
```

The JS that runs on the page is -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlModal;
    $('a[rel="edit"]').click(function() {
        urlModal = $(this).attr('href');
        $(urlModal).modal();
    });
});
```

Whenever I click on the `<a rel="edit">` button, the modal appears and immediately goes away.

Comment: did you try $(urlModal).modal('show'); ?

Comment: Just fixed the problem. Highly idiotic of me. Let me put it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the problem.

```
$('a[rel="edit"]').click(function() {
    urlModal = $(this).attr('href');
    $(urlModal).modal();
});
```

The `$(urlModal).modal();` part wasn't required. The code in the HTML part of the button, itself shoots the modal. And this query was closing it.

Now, its working.